# IntentsRule deprecated Espresso

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

I've been using a `BaseTest` class for Espresso something like this :

```
abstract class BaseTest<T : Activity> {

    val context: Context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext

    abstract fun getTestActivity(): IntentsTestRule<T>
    abstract fun startIntentActivity()

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    var activityTestRule = this.getTestActivity()

    fun launchActivity(intent: Intent?) {
        getTestActivity().launchActivity(intent)
    }

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        startIntentActivity()
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        activityTestRule.finishActivity()
    }
}
```

But now I'm seeing that `abstract fun getTestActivity(): IntentsTestRule<T>` is deprecated and we should use `ActivityScenario` and `ActivityScenarioRule` how should I modify that class to use the new clases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally one can provide the `Intent` either with Espresso - or an `ActivityScenarioRule`:

> `ActivityScenarioRule(Intent startActivityIntent)`
> Constructs ActivityScenarioRule with a given intent.

In Kotlin:

```
lateinit var scenario: ActivityScenario<SomeActivity>
val intent = Intent(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(), SomeActivity::class.java)

@get:Rule
val activityRule = activityScenarioRule<SomeActivity>(intent)

@Test
fun someTest() {
    scenario = rule.scenario
    scenario.onActivity { activity ->  
        ...
    }
}

@After
fun cleanup() {
    scenario.close()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but what about launchActivity function (that I send an intent) or the tearDown where I finishActivity() is not needed anymore?

Comment: @StuartDTO Added an example for `ActivityScenario` with an `Intent`... in order to generify this, you'd need to somehow pass an `Activity` class and an `Intent` instance .

Comment: But if I want to start activity then do I have to do something? Because I add the onView(...).click() and it does not start the new activity, any idea?

Comment: `scenario.onActivity {}` is automatically being called; there's no need to start anything.

Comment: In case you can help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67163964/how-to-combine-different-testinstrumentationrunner so I avoid the multi-comment